# Compare two arrays and check if have a same key's

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a compare two arrays and if I have differents keys, update both with same keys and 0 if not exist key before.

Eg.

```
let obj1 = [
{"type": "Riesenslalom","total": 2862},
{"type": "Slalom", "total": 362 },
{"type": "Super-G", "total": 579 }];

let obj2 = [
{"type": "Riesenslalom","total": 2218},
{"type": "Slalom","total": 448},
{"type": "Wall", "total": 133 }
];
```

My goal

```
let obj1 = [
{"type": "Riesenslalom","total": 2862},
{"type": "Slalom", "total": 362 },
{"type": "Super-G", "total": 579},
{"type": "Wall", "total": 0 }
];

let obj2 = [
{"type": "Riesenslalom","total": 2218},
{"type": "Slalom","total": 448},
{"type": "Super-G", "total": 0 }
{"type": "Wall", "total": 133 }
];
```

I tried different ways but can't solve this problem :(

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the arrays to a function - the first that you want to update, the second that you want to update from, and [loop over the objects in the first array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement). If the type value [isn't found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in an object in the second array update it with an "empty" object.

Return the updated array [sorting it by type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) if required.

Repeat the process by swapping the arrays around in the arguments.

```js
const arr1=[{type:"Riesenslalom",total:2862},{type:"Slalom",total:362},{type:"Super-G",total:579}],arr2=[{type:"Riesenslalom",total:2218},{type:"Slalom",total:448},{type:"Wall",total:133}];

function update(updateTo, updateFrom) {
  for (const { type } of updateFrom) {
    const found = updateTo.find(obj => obj.type === type);
    if (!found) updateTo.push({ type, total: 0 });
  }
  return updateTo.sort((a, b) => a.type.localeCompare(b.type));
}

console.log(update(arr1, arr2));
console.log(update(arr2, arr1));
```